# How to store single value for the database table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to store a single value for the database table. This is the counter updated from time to time. The value to be stored permanently. Whether to store a single value should build a separate model or use a different structure?

Answer (score 2):

Imho, it a good practice, to create some model that stores key-value data. It can be useful in future.

Comment: Do not be hypertrophy of form over content? A new model for a single value.